# Prevent npm from download all packages in private registry

Tags: npm, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Our company has a private npm registry hosted in Nexus. The problem I've run into is that first time a new project tries to install a package, npm downloads all the packages in in registry (over 200) into the node_modules folder. This causes a large delay, and isn't needed because only about 5 of the packages are actually needed.

The Nexus registry is setup with this URI:

https://nexus.domain.com:9999/content/groups/npm-all/

Is there a switch I can use that tells npm not to download all the packages from the private registry?

Answer (score 1):

You may think it only needs the 5 packages that are specified in your package.json, but truth is, packages have dependencies, which have dependencies and so on. That leads to the 200 downloads you're seeing and that is not wrong. Every time you remove your node_modules it will download everything it needs to resolve the dependencies.